# GDB / DDD no symbol <var> in current context

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, ddd-debugger

I found an old solution to this problem that suggested compiling with `-gdwarf-2`, but this solution does not or no longer work for me.

So, running ddd on a compiled file and then double clicking variables always results in the error `no symbol <var> in current context`

My program is this:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {

    }
}
```

the commands I used are these:

```
 g++ -g -O0 -gdwarf-2 test.cpp; ddd. ./a.out
```

Versions of the programs:

```
ddd: GNU DDD 3.3.12 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
gdb: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
gcc: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Since you are debugging with gdb/ddd, consider using `-ggdb` instead; I generally go with `-ggdb3` (which implies -g, so you only need the one option). -g3 results in significantly larger executable sizes due to the large amount of additional detail.

Comment: wait, so `g++ -ggdb -O0 program.cpp` ? That did not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print/display variables, they have to be in scope, so for local variables/parameters that means you have to be at a breakpoint in that scope.

I can reproduce the error you are getting by starting ddd with your example program and immediately trying to print/display `i`.

Once I set a breakpoint on the `for` line and run the program, I am able to print/display them as expected.

I compiled with:

```
g++ -Wall -O0 -ggdb -o test.exe test.cpp
```

and ran ddd with

```
ddd ./test.exe
```

I have

```
GNU DDD 3.3.12 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1)
```

Comment: that did it. I apparently had misunderstood how the display variable feature is meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just remove -gdwarf-2 from compile flags? I had a similar problem when using a new compiler on a system with an old debugger. Then the default debug symbol format used by the compiler was too new for the debugger and I had to make the compiler use an old format. This could be similar if the debugger was recently updated.

Comment: yes, I tried without `-gdwarf-2`. I only found that flag looking for a solution to that problem.

Comment: You still kept the -g flag rigth?

Comment: Could it be that you should keep -gdwarf-2 but remove -g?